# How to keep the basename of an input file and change its extension in Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

The following Nextflow scripts takes the $gtf as an input and outputs a .bed file. What I want is to keep just the basename of the gtf file and add the .bed extension to it. I tried declaring a variable x and using basename from bash but it gives error.

```
// Declare syntax version
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

/* 
 * pipeline input parameters 
 */

params.gtf_file = "$projectDir/data/Glycine_max.gtf"


    /*
 * define the `GTF2BED` process that creates a BED file
 * given the params.gtf_file as input. 
 */
 
process GTF2BED {

    input:
    path gtf

    output:
    "${gtf}/.bed"

    script:
    """
    gtf2bed --gtf $gtf --bed "${gtf}/.bed"
    """
}
```

Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getBaseName()`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes) method on `file` objects to get the basename:

> The invocation of any method name starting with the `get` prefix can be shortcut by omitting the `get` prefix and `()` parentheses. Therefore, writing `myFile.getName()` is exactly the same as `myFile.name` and `myFile.getBaseName()` is the same as `myFile.baseName` and so on.

For example:

```
process GTF2BED {

    input:
    path gtf

    output:
    path "${gtf.baseName}.bed"

    script:
    """
    gtf2bed --gtf "${gtf}" --bed "${gtf.baseName}.bed"
    """
}
```

If you need to remove a double extension (.e.g. `.tar.gz`) and don't want to remove all extensions (e.g. using the `getSimpleName()` method), you can use the long form to supply the number of extensions to remove. For example:

```
tarball = file( 'my.file.tar.gz' )

println( tarball.getBaseName(2) )
```

Prints:

```
my.file
```